# Substitute variables in PHP

Tags: php, variables

What is the best and easiest way to swap variables?

I have a PHP website with variables are across several PHP files. I want to be able to declare one variable in a global file and allow other files to select appropriate variables based on this.

Example:

**global.php**

```
$siteState = "Online";
//$siteState = "Testing";
//$siteState = "Local";
```

**db.php**

```
$dbHostOnline = "123.321.123.321";
$dbUsernameOnline = "root";
$dbPasswordOnline = "asdf";
$dbHostTest = "localhost";
$dbUsernameTest = "test";
$dbPasswordTest = "fdsa";
$dbHostLocal = "localhost";
$dbUsernameLocal = "root";
$dbPasswordLocal = "dsaf";
```

So, somehow when I select `$siteState = "Testing"` inside db.php it will select the `$dbHostTest`, `$dbUsernameTest` and `$dbPasswordTest` variables.

Any ideas? Something with Arrays maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Even though it is possible to do with using `{}` like

```
${'dbHost' . $siteState} = '...';
```

I strongly recommend you to look at arrays:

```
$options = array(
    'Online' => array('host' => '...', 'username' => '...'),
    'Test' => array('host' => '...', 'username' => '...'),
);

$current = $options[$siteState];
```

Comment: So you recommend to use global variables??

Comment: @OZ_: I said nothing about variables scope. The code sample I've given could be wrapped with function or class method, couldn't it?

Comment: You could then also use [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) to move those array elements into individual variables; `extract($options[$siteState])` to get `$host, $username` etc.

Comment: @zerkms it's very important so I think is better to write about it.

Comment: @Stephen Wood: yep, but array is a better container for that purposes, imho.

Comment: @OZ_: indeed it is important, but there are a lot of books and questions here about good design. Have no reason and wish to teach the best practices from the scratch, sorry.

Comment: @zerkms in question we definitely see example of using global variables.

Comment: @zerkms agreed, but if OP has code already written where those variables are needed then it might save time

Comment: @OZ_: indeed, we see it, but that is out of the subject. I don't want to start yet another topic about teaching newbies the best practices.

Answer (score 1):

You could quite simply do a switch in db.php on $siteState, and define each of $dbHost, $dbPassword for each case:

```
switch ($sitestate)
{
    case 'testing':
         $dbHost = '...';
         $dbUser = '...';
         ...
         break;
    case 'online':
         $dbHost = '...';
         $dbUser = '...';
         ...
         break;
    ...
}
```

And from there all scripts use the $dbHost, $dbPass etc variables, which will change depending on which $siteState you have set. This is easy to add/remove different states, and avoids the additional overhead of arrays as you will online ever need to access on set of $db variables.

**EDIT**

Another, perhaps better, way of defining this data would be to use constants given that db connection data isn't going to change, viz.:

```
case 'testing':
    define('DB_HOST', '...');
    define('DB_USER', '...');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the perfect time to look into switch-statements!
Just the standard link to the switch() PHP documentation ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)).

### Code example:

**db.php**

```
<?php
    switch($SiteState){
        case 'Online':
            $dbHost = "123.321.123.321";
            $dbUsername = "root";
            $dbPassword = "asdf";
            break;
        case 'Testing':
            $dbHost = "localhost";
            $dbUsernameOnline = "root";
            $dbPasswordOnline = "asdf";
            break;
        case 'Local':
            $dbHost = "localhost";
            $dbUsernameOnline = "root";
            $dbPasswordOnline = "asdf";
            break;
    }
?>
```

Didn't see Stephen Wood's answer before I posted, sorry.

Answer (score -2):

Never use global variables. **NEVER**.  Kick each one, who will recommend you to use global variables.
All constants should be declared in classes, which will use these constants (and they will be accessible for other classes).
And to not use "include" you can learn how to use namespaces and autoloading: http://groups.google.com/group/php-standards/web/psr-0-final-proposal?pli=1
In your case you can use different classes for testing.

Comment: Newbies with "-1" - comment your downvotes. I will explain you, what is your mistake, if you don't know it yet.

Comment: @Jitamaro what "this"? Using global variables is big mistake. Because your code becomes fragile because you can't move part of your code (where these global variables not declared), difficult errors and bugs appears because of names collisions.